# Uber Carthage swift LoginManager(loginType: .AuthorizationCode) giving accessToken=nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber SDK with my current iOS app.

I have Xcode :- 8.1 iOS :-10.1 and swift version :- 3.0

I have done setup for "Carthage" for Uber integration.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager(loginType: .AuthorizationCode)

loginManager.state = NSUUID().UUIDString

let requestedScopes = [RidesScope.Request, RidesScope.AllTrips]

loginManager.login(requestedScopes: requestedScopes, presentingViewController: self) { (accessToken, error) -> () in
}
```

accessToken alway nil.

Here is my plist for uber settings

```
<key>UberCallbackURIs</key> 
<array> 
    <dict> 
        <key>URIString</key> 
        <string>swiftsdk://connect</string> 
        <key>UberCallbackURIType</key> 
        <string>Implicit</string> 
     </dict> 
     <dict> 
        <key>URIString</key> 
                <string>swiftsdk://connect</string> 
        <key>UberCallbackURIType</key> 
                <string>AuthorizationCode</string>
     </dict>
     <dict> 
        <key>URIString</key>
                <string>swiftsdk://connect</string> 
        <key>UberCallbackURIType</key> 
                <string>Native</string>
      </dict> 
</array>    

<key>UberClientID</key>
        <string>ClientID</string> 
<key>UberClientSecret</key> 
        <string>ClientSecret</string> 
<key>UberDisplayName</key> 
        <string>Swift-SDK</string> 
<key>UberServerToken</key>
        <string>ServerToken</string>
```

Please help me.

i stuck here not able to execute my project. any suggestion will be useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you complete all steps from [official integration guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/ios#carthage)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i have followed Uber guide lines.

Comment: Here is my plist for uber settings

<key>UberCallbackURIs</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>URIString</key>
   <string>swiftsdk://connect</string>
   <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
   <string>Implicit</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>URIString</key>
   <string>swiftsdk://connect</string>
   <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
   <string>AuthorizationCode</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>URIString</key>
   <string>swiftsdk://connect</string>
   <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
   <string>Native</string>
  </dict>
 </array>

Comment: <key>UberClientID</key>
 <string>ClientID</string>
 <key>UberClientSecret</key>
 <string>ClientSecret</string>
 <key>UberDisplayName</key>
 <string>Swift-SDK</string>
 <key>UberServerToken</key>
 <string>ServerToken</string>